# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'future.builtins'; 'future' is not a package

Tags: python, sparklines

```
    import sparklines


ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-3de868bf8913> in <module>
----> 1 import sparklines

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sparklines\__init__.py in <module>
      5 
      6 if sys.version_info.major >= 3:
----> 7     from sparklines.sparklines import *
      8 else:
      9     from sparklines import *

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sparklines\sparklines.py in <module>
     15 import warnings
     16 
---> 17 from future.builtins import round # bankers' rounding for Python 2
     18 
     19 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'future.builtins'; 'future' is not a package
```

Comment: Did you install `future`?

Comment: yes,i have installed  future

Answer (score 0):

```
#Install 

! pip install sparklines

import sparklines
```